# How can I edit shapekey value without editing mesh?

Tags: shape-keys

I accidentally set shapekey value to 1 while editing mesh, but I actually wanted to it to be 0.5 How can I change shapekey value and keep it's mesh shape? I want to slide to 0.5 value to get my mesh shape, not to 1 to get it.

Comment: Under the "Value" slider adjust the Range's Max to 2 and increase the "Value" to 2. Then click on the little triangle under the minus button and select "new shape from mix". This will create a new shapekey what you expected. Delete the original and reset the settings.

Comment: @FFeller You should post that as an answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the *Value* slider adjust the Range's Max to 2 and increase the *Value* to 2. Every other Shape Key value must be 0.

Then click on the little triangle under the minus button and select *New Shape From Mix*. This will create a new shapekey with what you wanted. Delete the original and reset the settings.

[image]